# How do I put line break in p:tooltip

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tooltip

How can I put a line break to the PrimeFaces `tooltip` component to separate the first line from the second line?

```html
<p:tooltip id="toolTip"
           for="idButton"
           value="First line Second Line"
           position="top"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To show the tooltip with a line break you have to put it like this

```
<p:tooltip for="...">
    <h:outputText value="First line"/>
    <br/>
    <h:outputText value="Second line"/>
</p:tooltip>
```

Or using PrimeFaces Extensions (pe:tooltip)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
...

<pe:tooltip for="...">
    <h:outputText value="First line <br/> Second line" escape="false" />
</pe:tooltip>
```

https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=23196

Comment: You can also use `First line<br/>Second Line` as the direct content of the `p:tooltip`. So you don't **have** to put it in two `h:outputText`s separated by a `<br/> (although you **can**). And see my other answer. Effectively making both solutions overly complex.

Comment: the escape attribute does not work in p:tooltip that's why I created this question

Comment: According to the docs of 6.2 it does/should and I did use it. Not explicitly tested it recently, will do tonight. What is your version?

Comment: thanks, I'm using version 6.2, I've seen the documentation but and I can not run the escape attribute in the tooltip

Answer (score 7):

PrimeFaces tooltip supports the `escape` attribute since 5.1, so just do

```html
<p:tooltip id="toolTip"
           for="idButton"
           value="First line<br/> Second Line"
           position="top"
           escape="false"/>
```

But if you want to have a more 'visible' html, you can also do

```html
<p:tooltip id="toolTip" for="idButton" position="top">
    First line
    <br/>
    Second Line
</p:tooltip>
```

Comment: I have version 6.2 of primefaces and the escape attribute of the p:tooltip does not work, have you tried it?